# Is there a way to have an interface with a generic type extend another interface with another generic type in Java?

Tags: java

I would like to create a interface like this

```
public interface MyInterface<T extends OtherInterface<K>>{
    K doSomething(T o);
}
```

but the compiler won't recognize it.
The other way around is that:

```
public interface MyInterface<T extends OtherInterface<K>,K>{
    K doSomething(T o);
}
```

My question is, though the second code works, is there a way like the first code so I don't have to put two types to announce the interface?

Comment: No. Types have to be declared.

Comment: Also `T extends Comparable<K>` is weird.  Normally you want to be able to compare Ts: `T extends Comparable<T>`.

Comment: @markspace sorry for the confuse. Comparable is just an example here, it could be List or other interface.

Comment: @LuffyTse perhaps edit the question and change `Comparable` to `MyOtherInterface` or something of your choosing - just to remove the tie to `Comparable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an generic interface with two type arguments, then you need to declare them both in the class signature.

Alternatively if declare `K` as a wildcard `?` and just return `T`, you will still be able to cast the output `T` to the correct interface. eg:

```
interface Foo<T> { }

interface Bar<T extends Foo<?>>{
    T doSomething(T o);
}

class IntegerFoo implements Foo<Integer> {}
...

public static void main(String[] args) {
    IntegerFoo integerFoo = new IntegerFoo();

    Bar<IntegerFoo> bar = t -> t;

    Foo<Integer> result = bar.doSomething(integerFoo);
}
```